# Поиск чисел в строке и их сумма

Tags: java

Вообщем, существуют некие строки которые нужно проверить на наличие в них цифр, с этим все в порядке, но при выводе суммы этих чисел возникает ошибка

```
class Ideone {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Введите первую строку: ");
    String str = scanner.next();

    System.out.println("Введите вторую строку: ");
    String str1 = scanner.next();

    System.out.println("Введите третью строку: ");
    String str2 = scanner.next();

    if (!str.matches("^\\D*$")) {
        System.out.println("STR cодержит цифры!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("STR не содержит цифр!");
    }


    if (!str1.matches("^\\D*$")) {
        System.out.println("STR1 cодержит цифры!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("STR1 не содержит цифр!");
    }


    int count = 0, sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(str2.charAt(i))) {
            count++;
            sum += count;///////!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        }
    }
    if ((count >= 1) && (sum >= 1)) {
        System.out.println("STR2 содержит " + count + " цифр и их сумма = " + sum);
    } else {
        System.out.println("STR2 не содержит цифр, невозможно вычислить сумму!");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы суммируете не числа, но счётчик их количества. Т.е. цикл подсчёта суммы должен быть таков:

```
int count = 0, sum=0;
for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(str2.charAt(i))) {
        count++;
        sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueof(str2.charAt(i)));
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, вот только в строке "sum+=Integer.parseInt(str2.charAt(i));" несовместимость типов "char cannot be converted to String", не подскажите как ее решить?

Comment: @Bombucho, надо привести букву к строке. См. обновление ответа

Comment: все заработало , спасибо !

Comment: А что если число 2х или 3х значное???

Comment: @Андрей, по идее должно работать для чисел длиной от 0 до ~2 млрд знаков.